# Border with different width under Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, email-client

CampaignMonitor said CSS border property is accepted by all email clients.

I tried this:

```
.test1 {
border: 2px solid # 000000
border-width: 0 0 0 2px;
}
```

or this:

```
.test2 {
border-style: solid;
border-color: # 502090;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-right-width: 0 / * (| 0px | none) * /
border-bottom-width: 0;
border-left-width: 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work on Outlook 07/10/13.

I tried mso-border-* but there's always a border, even if I specify 0 as width.

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: you should post your HTML as well

Comment: Just an observation, but is the code in your .test1 example copied from your file?  Because if it is, you're missing a semi-colon on line 2 and that might account for the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, but I don't recommend it because of the curious proprietary implementation by Microsoft.

So, in conditionnal comment, I add this to have only top border :

```
.border {
mso-border-right-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;
mso-border-bottom-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;
mso-border-left-alt: none #FFFFFF 0;
mso-border-top-alt: solid #903010 2pt; /* px works too */
}
```

It works but this kind of border is outside the box (at least on Outlook 07/10/13).

Finally, I opted for fake borders made ​​with td background (and all the tricks to have thick width). Code is more complex and no easy to maintain, but it's the world on emailing (thanks to Microsoft)...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the html declaration `border=""`.

You should still be able to declare your color in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you try opening the same web page on Internet Explorer / Edge, you should now be able to copy and paste the table **without adding mso-border-*** code.